# Suspecting bug in Parallel Framework

Tags: bugs, parallelization, kernel

I've reduced my actual problem to:

```
ParallelEvaluate[
  Module[{slot=1},
    Slot[slot]
  ]
]
```

gives error messages that I think shouldn't be there. It seems I can work around them with

```
ParallelEvaluate[
  Module[{slot=1},
    Slot@@{slot}
  ]
]
```

and

```
ParallelEvaluate[
  Module[{slot=1,s=Slot},
    s[slot]
  ]
]
```

but I still think this is a bug in the parallel framework. Am I missing something obvious? It seems the numeric check happens with the local Module placeholder values passed to the parallelism framework in a syntactic way, not in a semantic way. But that's wrong, I should be able to pass `Slot[anything]`

v8.0.4 and v9 alike, Windows and Linux.

Comment: It happens on OS X as well (8 & 9) and even if you replace `Module` with `With`

Comment: These things happen when the expression is put in `Function`: `Function@Module[{s = 1}, Slot[s]]`.  Perhaps constructing a function is part of the parallel distribution/retrieval process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This message is issued by `Function` itself.  To see this, try

```
Function[Module[{slot = 1}, Slot[slot]]]
```

If `Function` has named formal parameters, the message goes away:

```
Function[x, Module[{slot = 1}, Slot[slot]]]
```

So to fix this first we need to find out where is the argument passed to `ParallelEvaluate` wrapped by `Function`.  Fortunately the parallel tools are defined in a plain `.m` (not `.mx`) file so we can read the source code.  The relevant part turns out to be in `$InstallationDirectory/AddOns/Applications/Parallel/Parallel.m`, in the definition of `Send`:

```
Send[kernels:{___kernel}, expr_] := Send[#, expr]& /@ kernels
```

The part causing the problem is `Send[#, expr]&`.  Looks innocent enough, doesn't it?  If we change this to `Function[k, Send[k, expr]]` then the message goes away.

**Warning:** I do not know if the form of `Function` with named formal parameters can cause any trouble (e.g. name collisions) in certain edge cases so be careful (or ask Leonid) ...  **Update:**  Here's an [example](http://weaklyreachable.blogspot.ca/2007/06/mathematica-pure-function-scope-problem_2182.html) of what may go wrong with named formal parameters.

Perhaps you can report this problem to WRI and let us know what they said.

---

Now that we know what the problem is caused by, we can manually construct simple problem cases.  For example,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Generally, passing any `Slot` not wrapped in a `Function` *without* formal arguments will cause problems (messages and unexpected results).  I would consider this a bug, so I think it's a good idea to report it.

Comment: Excellent diagnosis. Certainly a bug. Care to tag with [bugs]?

Comment: +1, but still waiting a few days for accept. I've already sent the programmer at WRI an email.

Comment: Nice work, earned a +1

Answer (score 10):

I would not classify this as a bug.  The behaviour of a `Slot` expression that is not directly contained within a `Function` expression is not defined by the documentation, and is unreliable in practice.  Consider the following two functions:

```
f[x_] := x + 100
g[x_] := x + # &[100]
```

They appear to be essentially equivalent, but it just so happens that the implementation of the second function involves a pure function.  However, they return different results when passed a "dangling" slot reference (i.e. a slot reference that is not directly contained within a pure function):

```
f[#]
(* 100 + #1 *)

g[#]
(* 200 *)
```

The second result might surprise us, especially if the documentation for `g` said "adds 100 to its argument".  Consider what happens if we call `g` with the `Module` expression from the question:

```
g[Module[{slot = 1}, Slot[slot]]]
(* 200 *)
```

`200` is perhaps not exactly what we expected, but at least it is consistent with `g[#]`.

On the other hand, let's try it with a new function `h` which is the same as `g` but holds its argument:

```
SetAttributes[h, HoldAll]
h[x_] := x + # &[100]

h[Module[{slot = 1}, Slot[slot]]]
(*
Function::slot: Slot[slot] (in Module[{slot=1},Slot[slot]]+#1&) should contain a non-negative integer. >>
(Module[{slot=1},Slot[slot]]+#1&)[100]
*)
```

We get the same warning message as in the question.  This occurs because this expression ultimately resolves to:

```
Module[{slot = 1}, Slot[slot]] &
```

... which is manifestly incorrect since arguments to `Slot` in a function body must be non-negative integers -- not symbols.

`ParallelEvaluate` happens to be implemented somewhat like `h`.  It holds the argument, and its implementation happens to use a pure function.

The moral of this story is that the behaviour of a dangling slot reference is essentially undefined.  Its behaviour depends upon the exact implementation of the functions to which it is passed.  If we are unaware of those exact implementation details, then we should avoid the use of dangling slot references since we can never be sure if that slot expression might not accidentally find its way into an internal `Function` expression.

To work around this difficulty, we can use a temporary symbol in place of `Slot` and then substitute it out after the evaluations are complete:

```
Module[{t}
, ParallelEvaluate[Module[{slot = 1}, t[slot]]] /. t -> Slot
]
```

This behaviour is just another example of the kind of "gotchas" that occur due to Mathematica's simulation of functional programming constructs through pattern matching techniques.

Comment: I agree in the sense that this is not a bug in `Function` or `Slot`, but this behavior should not be manifested in the ``Parallel` `` package. Actually I would argue that your `g` and `h` have a precedence bug; `g` should be defined as e.g. `g[x_] := x + (# &)[100]`, whereupon it gives the same result as `f`. The documentation implicitly countenances (in the Applications section) building expressions containing `Slot` without a containing `Function`--their example of `Function[Evaluate[f @@ Array[Slot, 5]]]` is logically identical to e.g. `With[{slots = f @@ Array[Slot, 5]}, Function[slots]]`.

Comment: @OleksandrR It is not always a simple matter to bulletproof a pure function body against injected slot references.  What about the `Send` function exhibited in @Szabolcs answer?  Named pure function arguments don't help either -- they have [problems of their own](http://weaklyreachable.blogspot.ca/2007/06/mathematica-pure-function-scope-problem_2182.html).  Even if such bulletproofing were simple, it is not common practice.  I'm not arguing that this behaviour is desirable, but I am saying that we shouldn't expect well-defined behaviour from an ill-defined language construct.

Comment: The problem is that there are no clear hints in the docs that there is anything wrong with using naked slots. As Oleksandr points out there is actually an example of programmatically constructing a pure function, which could be perceived as an encouragement to do such things. (I believe @Andreas must have been doing something similar: constructing code programmatically. Though it's true that combining this with parallel evaluation is a little unusual.) Also consider that `ParallelEvaluate` usually takes code as its argument, unlike most other functions. I wouldn't say that this problem was ...

Comment: ... easily avoidable.  So I'd still call this a bug, a usability bug if you like.  What's described in your blog I'd also call a bug (even if it's not really fixable given the design of the language ... )  It is very sad and unfortunate that Mathematica has these problem.  Lately I am never confident enough to try to use techniques like code generation/manipulation *in practice* (and not just for fun in a very simple scenario).  I can simply never feel confident enough that there is no input or edge case that could break my function.

Comment: @Szabolcs.  True the documentation has an example of generated slots, but the example conforms to my advice to only use it when the exact context is known (`f` has no definitions).  I totally agree to report it -- I reported the issue in my blog.  Sounds like a great _possible issue_ for the docs.  However, I anticipate the same response: avoid the situation. ...

Comment: @Szabolcs ... But to prohibit library code from referencing named arguments within a slotted pure function is far too draconian.  It is much easier to prohibit client code from using dangling slots -- it is rare and easily avoided.  I totally agree that it is unfortunate that these cases exist and that code generation can be very hard.  My strategy to cope with that is to try to avoid non-trivial evaluations within generation (e.g using `Hold`, `Block`, etc).

Comment: @WReach +1, agree with all your points. By the way, I wrote a tiny framework to resolve such nasty variable collisions / leaks as in your example in the blog. It lives [here](https://gist.github.com/1683497). When I call `runWithRenamings[ ClearAll[f, g]; f[x_] := g[Function[a, x]]; g[fn_] := Module[{h}, h[a_] := fn[a]; h[0]]; f[999]]`, I get the correct result. Of course this does not eliminate the problem, but it might be useful for debugging, and also one can run some code in a "safer mode", when wrapped in `runWithRenamings`.

Comment: @Leonid do you have any insight into why the renaming mechanism does not use unique symbols by default? If it would, we could safely use named arguments and this trouble with `Slot` would have a simple resolution. To me it seems absurd that conflicting symbols are renamed so predictably.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I really don't know. One blind guess is that this mechanism was designed / implemented quite a long time ago, and wasn't touched much after that. Also, the mechanism of emulation of lexical scope based on renamings seems to be inherently flawed, so one can *always* break it (intentionally). So perhaps, this fact was realized, and so the developers did not go further in making it (a little) safer since this does not fully solve the problem.  But I agree that, from the practical / user point of view, using fully unique symbols would be very helpful.

Comment: +1! I like how the 3 answers so far add important non-overlapping bits. I think it's a bug, since by default in Mathematica I think one should assume anything it's allowed as input. We don't need permission to take the square root of Lena. We need to be warned when some inputs can't be used. However, I agree that we should agree on not calling this a bug, or otherwise we'll end up with tons of similar bugs: as you said, too many functions don't work fine with hanging slots as input... as long as it isn't there in the possible issues of `Slot` as you suggested

Answer (score 8):

This is easily fixed by:

```
  Send[kernels:{___kernel}, expr_] := Table[Send[k, expr], {k, kernels}]
```

instead of

```
Send[kernels:{___kernel}, expr_] := Send[#, expr]& /@ kernels
```

While changing Parallel.m is one possibility, we can also
change the DownValues programmatically:

```
Parallel`Developer`Send;
Unprotect[Parallel`Developer`Send];
Parallel`Developer`Send[kernels : {___Parallel`Kernels`kernel}, expr_] := 
  Table[Parallel`Developer`Send[k, expr], {k, kernels}];
Protect[Parallel`Developer`Send];
```

This first idea is of giving  Send Attribute Listable
is wrong, thank's Oleksandr. Might be nice if there would be a ListableFirst attribute. But there is not.

Comment: The problem with this is that it needs to thread only over those lists appearing in the first argument. Personally, I'd rather do the threading explicitly than rely on the vagaries of `Listable`.

Comment: Just like Power[{1, 2, 3}, 2]. So what is vague here? Listable behavior is not going to change I guess.

Comment: You're probably right that it won't change. But what if someone wants to `ParallelEvaluate` a list that happens to be the same length as the list of kernels?

Comment: It's a nice idea to rely on `Listable` for a solution.  Hopefully this could be robust (unlike a `Function` with named arguments).

Comment: The only answer offering a simple good solution in the first lines, deserves more votes, +1!

Comment: @Rojo: Thanx. Do you have an idea how to do the DownValues replacement without using ToString? I tried, and it did not work ... (even with Verbatim all over the place).

Comment: @RolfMertig why not simply load the new definition?

Comment: @Rojo I don't like to directly change files in \$InstallationDirectory. It is usually better (updates, portability) to patch/bug-fix Mathematica explicitly. So The high-level patch could go somewhere in the application code (or $UserBaseDirectory init.m or on a webserver or wherever). The point is that I don't quite understand why I cannot Replace the InputForm of DownValues directly. I had to go through this ToString kludge. But I don't have time to delve deeper into it (probably it is also not that important, just intriguing).

Comment: @RolfMertig I mean, what about [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3k04u.png). Seems to work for me. What issue are you running into?